# responding to pings(discord.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm building a command that responds to pings in my discord.js bot. It doesn't work as expected even after using `<@BOTID>` and `@BOT#0000`, here's my code:

```
client.on('message', async (message) => {
  if (message.content === "@[☽♡☹♩] stylerr.#4162") {
    console.log("Someone pinged the bot! :P")
    message.channel.send("why'd you ping me lol")
  }
});
```

It doesn't work as expected though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bot probably has a nickname, so the tag will look like `<@!userid>`.
If it didn't have a nickname, it would be without the `!`.

Those are the only two ways a tag can look like.
You could account for this with a regex, e.g:
`<@!?userid>`<sup>[(demo)](https://regex101.com/r/UWZLXd/1)</sup>
`if (/<@!?userid>/.test(message.content))`

But really, you should probably use `message.mentions.has()`<sup>[(docs)](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=has)</sup>.